# How to get length of a nested JSON Array in Javascript

Tags: jquery

I have got this JSON

```
var data =
[
    {
        "new": [
            {
                "screen": "SCR2",
                "time_of_order": "20:08:58",
                "status": "Viewed",
                "item_id": "9,6,5,4",
                "quantity": "1",
                "vendor_id": "1",
                "order_id": "140827080458858O1O1",
                "json_value": [
                    {
                        "SurCharges": "50"
                    },
                    {
                        "SurCharges": "50"
                    },
                    {
                        "SurCharges": "50"
                    }
                ],
                "seat_number": "D12"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

How to get the length of a nested array named json_value ??

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/03zw041h/2/

Tried using

alert(data.new.json_value.length);

But console is reporting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'json_value' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some arrays in there

```
data[0].new[0].json_value.length
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/03zw041h/8/)

Comment: Ya beat me to it, next time I'll forego the fiddle :P

Answer (score 1):

You have nested arrays in there as well so you have to account for those.

http://jsfiddle.net/03zw041h/4/

`data[0].new[0].json_value.length`

Comment: Thank you very much , but i am facing issues when it comes to real time data in my project (more nested arrays present)so Is it possible to get the count of SurCharges present under the json_value??

Comment: If you're asking how to loop through those values and add them together you're better off posting another question, or just google arrays and looping.

Answer (score 0):

You have arrays of objects with only 1 element in each one, so maybe you don't want/need them as arrays:

```
var data =
{
    "new":
    {
        "screen": "SCR2",
        "time_of_order": "20:08:58",
        "status": "Viewed",
        "item_id": "9,6,5,4",
        "quantity": "1",
        "vendor_id": "1",
        "order_id": "140827080458858O1O1",
        "json_value":
        [
            {
                "SurCharges": "50"
            },
            {
                "SurCharges": "50"
            },
            {
                "SurCharges": "50"
            }
       ],
       "seat_number": "D12"
    }
};
```